# How to start animating folding fan like this?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

I'm having a bit of a problem on how to animate a foldable fan for an animation that I'm making

you twist the circular wire then it folds unto itself
How do I make this kind animation?
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

This is what I came up with using a curve circle and adding shapekeys.

[image]

[image]

I added the shapekeys in every frame of the timeline

since its a curve circle I also shaped key the mesh inside the curve circle trying my best to align them to each other but both are not calculating it the same way so I'm getting this
[image]
bad alignments on my animation.

Also I think my animation is not really representative of the look that I want.

Comment: Thanks. Another note that might help you get answers faster. You should show efforts towards reaching your goal, describing what you have tried and why it failed, so we don't risk recommending something you already know. The scope should also focus on a particular step you encountered an issue with. Describing the whole procedure from start to finish would be too lengthy to explain, and is beyond the goal of this site. Could you [edit] your post to focus on where you are stuck?

Comment: Thanks, I'll do this. 
Sorry I if don't know how to use the forum. 
is it possible to post gif or video here, and is it ok to post lengthy post?

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers